# How do I set a global #define in my C++ project?

Tags: c++

Because I always struggle to find the constructor in C++, I want to do something like this:

```
#define constructor
```

So I can type

```
constructor ClassName::ClassName() {}
```

Is there a good way to set this up so it's global for my project without having to actually define it inside every file?

I should mention I'm using Visual Studio if there is something specific to that involved.

(Or perhaps there is some other keyword similar to `override` that can be used for constructors?)

Comment: You could put it in a header file which you include from all headers. Or use an IDE that lets you find the constructor

Comment: @Yeats you write a header that says `#pragma once` then `#define constructor`. Then you include that header in every other header. Depending on how your solution is set up that might be as easy as adding it to the 'force includes' list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fi-name-forced-include-file?view=vs-2019

Comment: @JamesPicone My question is how to set it up globally.

Comment: @Yeats you can also use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Yeats it's an option that can be set on the project level to define a preprocessor macro for all translation units in Visual Studio. If you open your project properties and add 'constructor' to the list of preprocessor definitions, it will be present in all TUs.

Comment: @Yeats 'override' will cause a compilation error if the function does not actually override something.

Comment: @Yeats 1. any IDE show the symbols of the current class, usually is even the first method showed, you can easily find it in this way. 2. Usually constructors are stated first in class, so it is generally at the start from the file. If you have thousand of line or class in one file the problem is not the constructor. 3. almost any OO language define a constructor with the same name, so your argument is pointless

Comment: @Yeats if you write a function that is meant to override something without the override keyword and it doesn't actually override something, there is no compilation error. If you write a function that is meant to override something with the override keyword and it doesn't actually override something that is a compilation error - i.e. it changes the behaviour of the compiler, in a way that is actually quite useful if you intend to override a function. I'll write an answer.

Comment: There's a reason that's in literally no one's codebase. What you really want is to make sure at least your code is laid out in a sensible way. And get a symbol searcher like visual assist x for code monstrosities. It's particularly important not to stoop to shoddy practices as a beginner. And the override keyword is designed to prevent bugs, such as the case of refactoring a base function without considering the overrides, or inheriting a const function without the const specifier, happens more than you'd think.

Comment: @L.F. I was asking for a functionally useless keyword like `override` (which I thought was 100% functionless but I guess not) to mark constructors with. Like the way I add `override` on methods I override not because it changes anything, but to remind myself that I've overridden them. How is this hard to understand?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; use chat instead.

Comment: And everyone is bound by the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct); assume good intent and keep focused on getting an answerable question worked out.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a bad idea, for a few reasons:

- Macros are potentially quite dangerous. If you `#define constructor`, the token 'constructor' anywhere in your source will be replaced by empty space, which can be quite confusing. What if you have a variable named 'constructor' somewhere, or attempt to make one? What if a header you include - including the standard library - has a 'constructor' variable or type?
- While there are some keywords that you could put on the function that don't affect the semantics much and could act as an indicator, those keywords do actually do something and have meaning that will confuse other people reading your code
- If you are having trouble with the language to the point that finding constructors is hard, you are either using your IDE poorly or do not have the expertise required to use the language professionally, so marking constructors explicitly does not fix your true problem
- There are better alternatives.

One better alternative was suggested in the comments on your question - you can just use a comment that is the same everywhere:

```
class Foo {
    Foo(); // constructor
};
```

Now you can find constructors by searching for 'constructor'. If you want to be able to find constructors for a specific class by searching, you could do something like this:

```
class Foo {
    /* constructor */ Foo();
};
```

If you insist on doing this this is the approach I would suggest.

### An alternate approach:

I don't recommend that you do this. The comment approach should do what you want and is much less likely to mislead people reading your code or lead to unintended semantic changes. But if you insist on using a keyword, use the `explicit` keyword. Marking constructors as 'explicit' prevents you initialising an object like so: `Foo f = {1, 2}`, but not like so: `Foo f{1, 2}`. This is annoying but not fatal.

```
class Foo {
    explicit Foo();
}
```

Comment: I don't really think `explicit` is a good idea ...  If I see a default ctor marked `explicit`, I automatically think this class is special in some way (e.g., a tag class)

Comment: Yes, I don't like `explicit` either for that reason and that it's a little weird. I think I'll end up doing the commenting. Doesn't help me find constructors in other people's code, though, but neither does my global #define idea, so...

Comment: @L.F. I don't think it's a good idea either. I've updated the answer to be clearer on that front. I'm just presenting it as a possibility if the asker insists on not using comments (or their IDE)

Comment: @JamesPicone Marking a no-param ctor as explicit actually prevents copy initialization from `{}`, so for example `Class c = {};` will be affected :)

Comment: @L.F. Good point, updated answer.